# Updating Dash index_string from a callback for Jinja in Flask integration

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, plotly-dash

Plotly Dash uses the index_string value to customize the Dash's HTML Index Template as explained [here](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources).

To integrate Dash with Flask, one can pass Flask app as Dash server, and get back the Flask app with the Dash app integrated in it, also taking advantage of Jinja. This approach is nicely explained in several tutorial, such as [this one](https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/).

If you want to add a Jinja template, you can pass the HTML template to the code initializing Dash. The index string shall contain the {%" + filed + "%} required by Dash, but rendering the template will escape that code.

A trick is nicely explained in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827099/passing-dash-html-components-into-a-jinja-template), where the HTML is enriched with comments, which are ignored by Jinja during the rendering, and then replaced in the code with the fields for Dash before setting the index_string upon Dash app initialization.
This effectively works, the dash app is well integrated in the Flask server, and the Jinja template is inegrated and rendered.

Here some code to frame this a bit more concretely:

```
def init_dashboard(server,url):
"""Create a Plotly Dash dashboard."""
dash_app = dash.Dash(
    server=server,
    routes_pathname_prefix=url,
    external_stylesheets=[
        "/static/dist/css/styles.css",
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato",
    ],
)
 # Both app context and a request context to use url_for() in the Jinja2 templates are needed
with server.app_context(), server.test_request_context():
    #items = Item.query.all()
    html_body = render_template_string(html_layout)

    comments_to_replace = ("metas", "title", "favicon", "css", "app_entry", "config", "scripts", "renderer")
    for comment in comments_to_replace:
        html_body = html_body.replace(f"<!-- {comment} -->", "{%" + comment + "%}")

    dash_app.index_string = html_body
# Load DataFrame
df = create_dataframe()

# Create Layout
dash_app.layout = my_layout
init_callbacks(dash_app)
return dash_app.server
```

With the layout in HTML:

```
    html_layout = """
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Calculator 
{% endblock %}


 {% block content %}
 <body class="dash-template">
            <header>
              <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <!-- <a href="/">
                    <img src="/static/img/logo.png" class="logo" />
                    <h1>Plotly Dash Flask Tutorial</h1>
                  </a> -->
                <nav>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </header>
            <!-- app_entry -->
            <footer>
              <!-- config -->
              <!-- scripts -->
              <!-- renderer -->
            </footer>
        </body>
 {% endblock %}
"""
```

Now, the problem I have is that I would like to *update* the index_string in the Dash_app during the execution, for example during a callback, and not only on initialization.
Upon debug, I can get the dash_app embedded in the Flask app with the dash.get_app() function. There, I can find my index_string nicely set. But I could not find a way to *set* back that index_string value, effectively updating the dash template. Do you have any idea on how I could achieve this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution, but it is *super hacky*, and I *really* would like something a bit more robust and elegant, so whoever has an idea, please share it!

The solution is by setting your `index_page` like this: your app exists in `dash.dcc._dash._get_app.APP`

You can modify it from within a dash callback code, from where the variable is visible.

and you can set the `index_page` attribute directly in the `dash_app` using `setattr` like this:

```
html_body = render_template_string(html_layout, variable_for_jinja=value)
comments_to_replace = ("metas", "title", "favicon", "css", "app_entry", "config", "scripts", "renderer")
for comment in comments_to_replace:
    html_body = html_body.replace(f"<!-- {comment} -->", "{%" + comment + "%}")
setattr(dash.dcc._dash._get_app.APP,"index_string",new_index_page)
```